# PHP save content from textarea with newline

Tags: php, mysql, textarea, newline

This is probably really stupid, but I try to save content from a texarea into MySQL with PHP. Normally newlines are preserved in the database. But suddenly they are removed.

I use jquery to send the values to PHP with ajax, and then I do this in PHP:

```
$var   = strip_tags( $_POST["var"] );
$db->query("UPDATE table SET var='$var' WHERE id=$id")
```

Somehow newlines are lost on the way in. If I do nl2br on the var, then they are translated to `<br/>`, so $var contains newline right up until I run the query.

Update, to add to the strangeness. If I actually run nl2br on $var, and then replace br-tags with newline, before updating the table, all is well, what is going on?!?

This is working just fine:

```
$var   = strip_tags( $_POST["var"] );
$var = nl2br($var);    
$var = preg_replace('#<br\s*/?>#i', "\n", $var);
$db->query("UPDATE table SET var='$var' WHERE id=$id");
```

Comment: Do you see newlines in Database itself? May be you should use nl2br on rendering side.

Comment: use nl2br.  like  $var   = nl2br(strip_tags( $_POST["var"] ));

Comment: No I don't see newlines in the database. And if I run nl2br on rendering side, then no <br/>-s appear.

Comment: @Anant, I don't wan't to save <br / > in the database.

Comment: What is the type of `var` in your database ?

Comment: The type is tinytext.

Comment: @user1695602   you have to otherwise you cannot show it with newlines after fetching from db.. check this link and see all the answers:-  https://www.google.co.in/search?q=PHP+save+content+from+textarea+with+newline&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&ei=EsXbV-LiOePI8AepiI6YBA

Comment: No you don't. You just use nl2br when displaying the text. Not when saving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had another look into the Zebra (source code this time), and as mentioned in previous comment this is exactly why newlines get removed. The escape method from Zebra package uses:
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

which means the following are removed:
NUL (ASCII 0), \n, \r, \, ', ", and Control-Z.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add the input in:

```
<pre></pre>
```

This will save your input as preformatted text in the database.

Reference: https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/pre

[nl2br](http://php.net/nl2br) is a good solution too, use whichever you prefer.
Also make sure you are using the right configuration for your database column. It should be VARCHAR or TEXT.

Comment: That doesn't really solve the problem. My problem is that \n is removed when saving. I don't want to save html together with the text.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that newlines get removed before being passed to the server.

You mentioned it's being sent with jQuery so make sure there isn't any client-side processing before being sent to the server.

Comment: The thing that is strange is that if I do nl2br($var) before running the query, then I do get <br>-tags. 

So I wonder if the newlines is being stripped away when I actually run the query? I use Zebra_database wrapper. If I eg. go into PhpMyAdmin en edit the text, then newlines are preserved. So there is nothing wrong with the database or datatype.

Comment: I had a quick look into the Zebra docs and it seems that the update() method calls escape() which:
"Escapes special characters in a string that's to be used in an SQL statement in order to prevent SQL injections.

This method also encloses given string in single quotes!"

http://stefangabos.ro/wp-content/docs/Zebra_Database/Zebra_Database/Zebra_Database.html#methodescape

So that's why your newlines get removed.

Comment: Aha, I had a feeling this would be the issue, it is not so long ago that I switched to Zebra_database. I wonder what is best practice to perserve linebreaks then?

Comment: Personally I prefer PDO and bound parameters rather than escaping the SQL string.